# Nuxt i18n wait for page components to load before changing lauguage specific texts on default.vue

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

Right now I'm prefetching all the global labels through out the site and storing them in vuex. I then get them in default.vue via a computed method, so every time the lang changes I get the updated list of labels:

default.vue

```
 computed : {
        translations : function(){
            return this.$store.getters['getTranslationsByLocale'](this.$i18n.locale);
        }
}
```

Problem is that when I change the locale (with a lang switcher link) the labels in default.vue render before the main nuxt component loads. I would like to wait for the nuxt component to load and then render the labels with the new lang texts.

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with the first charge. I was shown components outside of `<Nuxt />`, and then the entire content of a given subpage.

I solved the problem with the v-if directive on `<v-app>`. The default is **false**, but this value is changed when hook mounted is started. Below is the code for the **default.vue** file.

```
<template>
  <v-app v-if="loading">
    <nuxt />
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      loading: false,
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.loading = true
  },
}
</script>
```